# How to append a column by matching two columns from different dataset?

Tags: r

I have two dataset. I want to add a new column "Price" in df1 which is is in df2 by matching column names.

df1

```
Name Plan      
    A    P1
    B    P2
    A    P3
    C    p4
```

df2

```
Name   Plan  Price

    A    P1   1 
    B    P2   2
    A    P3   3 
    C    p4   4
```

Take p1 from df1 and if it's found in df2 take the corresponding Price and mutate it with p1 in df1.

OUTPUT
df1

```
Name   Plan  Price

    A    P1   1 
    B    P2   2
    A    P3   3 
    C    p4   4
```

Comment: your ouput df1 looks exactly like df2? Is this supposed to be the case?

Comment: looks like a simple `merge`, `merge(df1, df2)`

Comment: No, the plans in the df2 is not in the same order as df1.